# NDepend how to export all types that I use from .NET frameworks in my assembly

Tags: cql, ndepend

I'm not a .NET developer, but I need to solve one simply task: Create report that will contain all types from .Net frameworks that are using in given assembly.
When I open the assembly in VisualNDepend I see that I need in ClassBrowser, but I don't know how to export all of these lists to file.
If I understand correctly I need to create correct CQL query and then export it on desired format.
Can you help me with this query? Thank.

Answer (score 1):

The CQLinq code query you can write is:

```
// <Name>All .NET Fx types used</Name>
from t in ThirdParty.Assemblies.WithNameWildcardMatchIn(
   "mscorlib",
   "System*",
   "Microsoft.*",
   "Presentation*").ChildTypes()
select t
```

Basically here we are asking for third-parties assemblies, filtered by name wildcard patterns, that match only .NET Fx assemblies. And then we call `ChildTypes()` to get all types of these assemblies.

Notice that NDepend only gather third-party types used by the application, so you won't get unused types in the result.

Notice that by changing `ChildTypes()` to `ChildMethods()` or `ChildFields()` or `ChildNamespaces()` you can get the methods, fields or namespaces of .NET Fx used.

To get such query (that is not a rule violated) listed in the report, you need to get the query saved in a group where you applied **List Code Queries of this Group in a dedicated section in Report**.

[image: NDepend list code queries in report]

If you want to bypass the report, you can also export the result to HTML or XML format:

[image: Export NDepend code query result]